# Need DataFram.Replace help of pandas of Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I am new in Python and trying to replace strings using DataFrame.Replace of 'pandas' but facing problem. The tab separated text file as follows:

```
                            RepStr         KeyStr                ValStr
0                        S Connery      S Connery          Sean Connery
1                       S. Connery     S. Connery          Sean Connery
2                      Connery, S.    Connery, S.          Sean Connery
3        Connery, S; Blofeld, E.S.     Connery, S          Sean Connery
4   Connery; Moore, R.; ES Blofeld        Connery          Sean Connery
5                        R Moore R    Moore Roger                 Moore
6                         R. Moore       R. Moore           Roger Moore
7                        Moore, R.      Moore, R.           Roger Moore
8   ES Blofeld; Connery; Moore, R.     ES Blofeld  Ernst Stavro Blofeld
9            E.S. Blofeld; Connery   E.S. Blofeld  Ernst Stavro Blofeld
10                    E.S. Blofeld   E.S. Blofeld  Ernst Stavro Blofeld
11                         Blofeld        Blofeld  Ernst Stavro Blofeld
12          Blofeld, E.S.; Connery  Blofeld, E.S.  Ernst Stavro Blofeld
```

I am trying to replace in "RepStr" column the matches as per the "Key: Value" pair from "KeyStr" column and "ValStr"  column as variable. It is working for direct values for complete cell.

```
import pandas as pd
pipe_data = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/NStd.txt', sep='\t')
NStd = pd.DataFrame(pipe_data)
NStd.replace(to_replace={'RepStr':{'KeyStr': 'ValStr'}}, inplace=True)
NStd
```

How to get my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a replacement series `s`, then use`Series.replace` with optional parameter `regex=True` to replace the values in `RepStr` with the corresponding values from `s`:

```
s = df.set_index('KeyStr')['ValStr']
s.index = r'(?:(?<=;\s)|(?<=^))' + s.index + r'(?=;|$)'
df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].replace(s, regex=True)
```

---

```
0                                        Sean Connery
1                                        Sean Connery
2                                        Sean Connery
3                  Sean Connery; Ernst Stavro Blofeld
4     Sean Connery; Roger Moore; Ernst Stavro Blofeld
5                                           R Moore R
6                                         Roger Moore
7                                         Roger Moore
8     Ernst Stavro Blofeld; Sean Connery; Roger Moore
9                  Ernst Stavro Blofeld; Sean Connery
10                               Ernst Stavro Blofeld
11                               Ernst Stavro Blofeld
12                 Ernst Stavro Blofeld; Sean Connery
Name: RepStr, dtype: object
```

Comment: It is only **replacing the first name** before semicolon and **not others after the semicolon**

Comment: Your questions seems unclear, so you want to replace all the values and not just from the corresponding rows?

Comment: If you see the **first column (RepStr)** then you will find that **the names are separated by semicolons and space (; )**. I want to replace **all the names in the cell (RepStr)** to standard names (ValStr) as per the KeyStr.

Comment: @Satya Can you give the example of output for the string `Connery, S; Blofeld, E.S.`

Comment: `Connery, S; Blofeld, E.S.`   Needs to be changed  `Sean Connery; Ernst Stavro Blofeld`

Comment: I am facing a typical problem in the following code:

`s = df.set_index('KeyStr')['ValStr']
s.index = r'(?:(?<=;\s)|(?<=^))' + s.index + r'(?=;|$)'
df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].replace(s, regex=True)`

If the number of rows in `s.index` is less than `df['RepStr']` then it is showing the error 
**TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**

Is there any solution?